# How do I check that a payment was made and completed successfully? (Stripe)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe, when users click "subscribe" and pay the fee, how do I then know that they've paid it? Does stripe return something?

Answer (score 0):

When you make a [`Stripe::Subscription.create()`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#create_subscription) call, it will throw an [error](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#errors) if the subscription creation or payment fails - and you can use the error type to determine why it happened.

Comment: but if payment succeeds, how do I know?

Comment: It will not throw an error if it succeeds - so if your code continues on, the payment succeeded.

Is that what you mean?

Comment: right. I think I overthought it, I was thinking of doing something like `charges =  Stripe::Charge.create...` and then `if charges.paid == true` I would know the payment succeeded.